# register log4j 1.x as MXBean in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know how can I register log4j 1.x as an MXBean. I saw that version 2 has a very nice interface with JMX but not 1.x.

I need 1.x because at this point I cannot update log4j version.

I searched over the internet trying to find a solution for this problem but without success.

Some say that there is a class which you can add in application context like this

```
<bean name="jmxLog4j" class="org.apache.log4j.jmx.HierarchyDynamicMBean">

</bean>
```

but I had no luck with this. I cannot figure out why it isn't working.

Others say that you can create a custom interface of the MXBean and implement it but I don't want to use this solution.

So, the question is a very simple one. How can I register log4j versions 1.x (I think I have 1.4) as an MXBean to be used with JMX?

Comment: Hope this may help you . http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2008/06/change-logging-levels-using-jmx-howto.html?_sm_au_=iHVSR0Vr12tTM1rH

Comment: It's not the answer I was looking for. The URL you provided gets me to a place where it tells me to write a custom implementation for the MBean. What I want is to use the existent one from log4j.

Comment: Just having that bean is not enoght, you also have to setup the JMX infrastructure http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html

Comment: This helped a lot! I already had it set and the problem was that I had multiple application contexts used independently for each environment. The problem was that I used another context file. Thanks!